# Converting '5%' into actual 5%

Tags: python, string-conversion

not sure how many things I'm doing wrong here, I get "could not convert string to float: '5%'. 
Code is below, any insights appreciated.... many thanks.

```
tip=input("How much would you like to tip on your US$88.5 cheque, 5%, 12.5%?")

cheque = 88.5

total= cheque*(float(tip)+1)

print("Thank you, the total will be total $%.2f" % (total))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when you enter percentage.
Works with 5% or 5, too.

```
tip=raw_input("How much would you like to tip on your US$88.5 cheque, 5%, 12.5%?").rstrip("%")

cheque = 88.5

total = cheque*(float(tip)/100)+cheque

print("Thank you, the total will be total $%.2f" % (total))
```

Comment: Not if you enter the totally reasonable value `5%`. The answers in the duplicate do address that.

Comment: @RadLexus I fixed the code now.

Comment: It's still a duplicate, so you are better off answering in there. (There is no answer yet that uses `rstrip`, and *technically* the ones using `strip` are wrong because they allow `%5` as valid input.)